# PhpStorm Settings - How to adjust the time delay for inspection tooltips and pop-ups

Tags: phpstorm, tooltip, settings

It can be incredibly annoying when your mouse rests - for just a fraction of second - and all sorts of suggestions and inspections and tooltip pop-up's are jumping up all over the place in PhpStorm.

Is there a way to adjust the time delay for these?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to adjust the time delay for for inspection tooltips and pop-ups:

```
path: Settings - Editor - Code Editing - Editor tooltips (default is 500 ms)
```